# Mixing has_one and belongs_to for bidirectional association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In the following (fictional) example, each Post has been created by exactly one User. For performance reasons, we need to "write down" the first post a user has ever made. Therefore, the schema looks like this:

[image: ERD]

My question now is, how to model this with Active Record? Is the following correct?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_post, :class_name => 'Post'
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user      # has_many would be wrong, as a
                     # post can't be the first post of
                     # more than one user.
end
```

Comment: May be you have to change `has_one :user` in your `Post` model to something like `has_one :owner, :class_name => 'User'`.But having this along with `belongs_to :user` doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't need the two associations in your `Post` class. You should be able to get the behaviour you want like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :first_post, :class_name => 'Post'
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is because your second association is just a specialised case of the `has_many` association. Each post *already* has a `user_id` associated with it; you don't have to add an extra one for your `first_post` case.

However, given that you probably won't want to do anything except access this user's first post (and thus won't need [the extra methods added by `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.17/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs_to)), it might be clearer to write this as a normal method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def first_post
    Post.find(first_post_id)
  end
end
```